# Activate bash and pass it "single line code" instead of file

Tags: bash

I have scripts that are in text mode(no individual files) and are actually large scripts, each clustered in one line. For example a grep-like script:

```
searchWord=""; for file in *; do <do stuff 1>;...<do stuff 20>; done;
```

Directly passing this "text" to bash doesn't work because it expects a file:

```
>bash searchWord="end"; <create filelist>; for file in *;...
searchWord=end: No such file or directory
```

As I need the scripts to stay in 1 line each, but they require bash - how can i activate bash and pass this within the same line?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with _they are in text mode (no file)_. Could you clarify? Given a string like `searchWord=""; for file in *; do <do stuff 1>;...<do stuff 20>; done;`, just running it in the console suffices, you do not need to invoke any bash

Comment: Actually, you do, if the file system is normaly in "ksh mode", but you have bash specific script. 
I work with multiple virtual file systems and some of these scripts are dangerious, so they can't be permanently put onto the systems. So they are kept in txt file and can easily be used via copy-paste.

Comment: I still don't understand this. You probably want to run `bash` and, once in bash, paste the command.

Comment: Correct, but, even tho it sounds silly, this wastes time.

Comment: Well you can always say `bash -c 'command'`, like `bash -c 'uptime; echo 23'`

Comment: First start `bash`, copy-paste the lines you want to execute from your `allcommands_copypaste_please.txt` and use `exit` to return to your original shell.

Comment: Well, bash -c 'command' is a solution, it requires a bit of escaping, but its understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elaborating on fedorqui's and Yani Maltsev's comments:

```
bash -c 'searchWord=""; for file in *; do <do stuff 1>;...<do stuff 20>; done'
```

or

```
bash -c "searchWord=''; for file in *; do <do stuff 1>;...<do stuff 20>; done"
```

If you use either single quotes outside and only double quotes inside, or else double quotes outside and only single quotes inside, no escaping will be needed.